# while loop can't detect a simple math operation

Tags: c, while-loop, codeblocks

I was trying to understand how while loops work and how to use them so I tried to make a loop where the code removes 50 points from a variable a named health until the variable = 0 but for some reason it can't detect the operation that removes points so it just keeps printing "player has 100 health".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*this is me just messing around and learning*/;
    int health=100;
    while (health>0)
        printf("player has %d HP\n",health);
    health=health-50;
    printf("player took -50 damage ");
    printf("player has %d HP\n",health);
    if(health<20)
        (printf("low on health?"));
    else
        printf("that will leave a mark");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn to format your code!

Comment: Your while loop contains only the `printf()` statement; and the value of `health` does not change, so that if it loops at all, it keeps on looping, and since `health` is set to `100`, it stays at `100` until you get fed up and interrupt or otherwise kill the process.  Use braces around the body of the loop — the set of statements you wish to be executed in the loop.  The parentheses around `(printf("low on health?"));` are aconventional and unnecessary — `printf("low on health?");` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope the code belonging to the `while` loop using curly braces.  You probably intended to do this:

```
while (health > 0) {
    printf("player has %d HP\n", health);
    health = health - 50;
    printf("player took -50 damage ");
    printf("player has %d HP\n", health);
    if (health < 20) (printf("low on health?"));
    else printf("that will leave a mark");
}
```

Your current code, as it stands now, will just loop indefinitely, printing `player has 100 health`, because the while loop's body is just defaulting the `printf` statement on the immediate next line.